# Displaying data in two separate columns based on where clause in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a system that has to display a students marks
How can I write my query such that it shows the exam mark and ca mark without showing the zeros, and also be able to properly group by subject ID, not duplicate the subject name

A subject must only appear once with the corresponding CA and Exam mark.

I tried group concat and distinct but no avail.

When I run this query

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT marks.student_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.subject_name) AS subject_name,
    subjects.id as sub_id,
    (
        CASE WHEN assessements.assessement_type = 1 THEN (
            SELECT
                ROUND(AVG(marks.mark)) as ca_average
            FROM
                marks
                INNER JOIN assessements ON assessements.id = marks.assessement_id
                INNER JOIN teaching_loads ON teaching_loads.id = marks.teaching_load_id
                INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.id = teaching_loads.subject_id
            WHERE
                marks.student_id = 576
                AND assessements.assessement_type = 1
                AND assessements.term_id = 2
                AND subjects.id = sub_id
            ORDER BY
                subjects.id
        ) ELSE 0 END
    ) as ca,
    (
        CASE WHEN assessements.assessement_type = 2 THEN (
            SELECT
                marks.id
            FROM
                marks
                INNER JOIN assessements ON assessements.id = marks.assessement_id
                INNER JOIN teaching_loads ON teaching_loads.id = marks.teaching_load_id
                INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.id = teaching_loads.subject_id
            WHERE
                marks.student_id = 576
                AND assessements.term_id = 2
                AND assessement_type = 2
                AND assessements.term_id = 2
                AND subject_id = sub_id
            ORDER BY
                subjects.id
        ) ELSE 0 END
    ) as exam
FROM
    marks
    INNER JOIN assessements ON assessements.id = marks.assessement_id
    INNER JOIN teaching_loads ON teaching_loads.id = marks.teaching_load_id
    INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.id = teaching_loads.subject_id
WHERE
    marks.student_id = 576
GROUP BY
    subjects.id,
    assessements.assessement_type
```

This is what the query produces

[image: Query result]

How can I write my query such that it shows the exam mark and ca mark without showing the zeros, be able to properly group by subject ID,

Something like this

```
**Student ID | Subject Name | sub_id | ca | exam**    
   576             English      2     40    54     
   576             Geography    34    30    34
```

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` when you're using `GROUP BY`, since the grouping ensures that you don't get duplicates.

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subject_name)` to get rid of duplicates there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use sub-queries, use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
    marks.student_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.subject_name) AS subject_name,
    subjects.id as sub_id,
    ROUND(
      AVG(
        CASE WHEN assessements.assessement_type = 1
              AND assessements.term_id = 2
             THEN marks.mark
        END
      )
    )
     AS ca,
    ROUND(
      AVG(
        CASE WHEN assessements.assessement_type = 2
              AND assessements.term_id = 2
             THEN marks.mark
        END
      )
    ) as exam
FROM
    marks
    INNER JOIN assessements ON assessements.id = marks.assessement_id
    INNER JOIN teaching_loads ON teaching_loads.id = marks.teaching_load_id
    INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.id = teaching_loads.subject_id
WHERE
    marks.student_id = 576
GROUP BY
    marks.student_id,
    subjects.id
```

`CASE` expressions that don't have an `ELSE` implicitly return `NULL` is none of the `WHEN` clauses return `TRUE`.

Also `AVG()` and other aggregates essentially ignore `NULL` values.  This means that the average of `NULL, 1, 2, 3` is `2`.

Using these together, the above code returns the average of `marks.marks` for `assessement_type = 1` in one columns, and the average of `marks.marks` for `assessement_type = 2` in a separate column.